# Keep a task grunt task open

Tags: socket.io, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a grunt task that kicks off a socket-io server among other things.

I have found a way of keeping the task 'open' (ie, not exiting straight away on the command line) by running the 'watch' task right after it. e.g

`grunt.registerTask('default', ["mytask", "watch"]);`

But this requires me to fill in some dummy data in the Gruntfile such as.

```
// Not needed...
watch: {
  files: "test/*"
},
```

So is there a way to keep my task running without having to use the watch task along with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

> Tasks can be asynchronous.

```
grunt.registerTask('asyncfoo', 'My "asyncfoo" task.', function() {
    // Force task into async mode and grab a handle to the "done" function.
    var done = this.async();
    // Run some sync stuff.
    grunt.log.writeln('Processing task...');
    // And some async stuff.
    setTimeout(function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('All done!');
        done();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into grunt

```
grunt.registerTask('asyncme', 'My asynchronous task.', function() {
   var done = this.async();
   doSomethingAsync(done);
});
```